# How can I set x.foo = y during a Linq Join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've defined entities Foo and Bar such that Foo has a non-mapped Bar. The reason that Bar is non-mapped, is that a given Foo can map to many different single Bars potentially, depending on a GroupingId that's passed in when the code is executed.

My goal is to pass back a collection of Foo entities with the Bar navigation property in place (if it exists), below is the code I currently have attempting to do this, unsuccessfully.

```
var stuff = _Repository.Find<Foo>(x => Codes.Contains(x.Code))
.GroupJoin(_Repository.Find<Bar>(y => y.GroupingId == groupingId),
x => barId, 
y => Id, 
(x, y) => x.Bar = y.FirstOrDefault());
```

The error is that the type arguments cannot be inferred from usage, which I believe is because I'm not specifying that I need to return x after binding y to the Bar property.

Do I need to declare an Anonymous function to do this, and will that work with Entity Framework?

Comment: Don't mutate the object in the query, create a new object that has all of the information you want to have.

Answer (score 4):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  If you want to update then you can create a query to get all of the data you need and then change them with a `foreach`:

```
var stuff = _Repository.Find<Foo>(x => Codes.Contains(x.Code))
                       .GroupJoin(_Repository.Find<Bar>(y => y.GroupingId == groupingId),
                                  x => barId, 
                                  y => Id, 
                                  (x, ys) => new {x, ys});

foreach(var s in stuff)
{
   s.x.Bar = s.ys.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Does it actually prevent you from updating, or is that just best practice? I know you cannot swap the object you get (like foreach?!), but can you change fields and other properties on it?

Comment: There are _ways_ to update but they are ugly not good practice.  It's not as simple as changing a projection to an assignment.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Enumerating the Queryable? Ideally I'd like to be able to apply a couple additional filters before executing the query.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but you can always tack on a `Where` clause - either to the base query or within the `foreach` (`foreach(var s in stuff.Where( /* filter */))`)